# Delphi Timer issue

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
   i : integer;
begin
  if i > StrToInt(Edit1.Text) then
    Timer1.Enabled := False
  else
    i :=+ 1;
  SendClick(645,302);
  Sleep(2200);
  SendClick(694,619);
  Sleep(2200);
  SendClick(967,638);
  Sleep(2200);
  SendKeys('{BKSP}{BKSP}{BKSP}{BKSP}1',False);
  SendClick(917,688);
  Sleep(2200);
  SendClick(917,688);
  Sleep(2200);
  SendClick(917,688);
  amount := StrToInt(Label3.Caption) + 1;
  Label3.Caption := IntToStr(amount);
end;
```

for some reason it repeats only 1 time and stops... can anyone spot a problem? im pretty tired and ive went over and over it a few times and i can't seem to see one...

Comment: yes i know i could use a for loop...and it works fine as a for loop...but it freezes the dialog box until its finished...that why i desided to use a timer...

Comment: This _is_ some roundabout way of making a loop...

Comment: Your real question should be to ask how to do this properly, without SendKeys, SendClick or any of that nonsense.

Comment: @David I'm just getting back into delphi...eventually i plan on making it find the screen position of the window and target it and base the clicks on the window width / height ect..if you feel like doing all that work for me be my guest.. until then i guess ill use my crappy newb way..

Comment: do it your way if you prefer, but I'm sure there are plenty of people here that would be happy to guide you to a cleaner solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I is a uninitialized local variable (it contains garbage), so the result of the comparision if i > StrToInt(Edit1.Text) is random.

You may want to add a member variable to your form's class, initialize at the proper time and check it's value on the onTimer event, something like:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    FTimerCount: Integer;
    FMaxTimerCount: Integer;
    ..


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTimerCount := 0;
  FMaxTimerCount := 20;  //the timer will fire 20 times.
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Inc(FTimerCount);
  Timer1.Enabled := FTimerCount < FMaxTimerCount;
  DoOtherStuff();
end;
```

Comment: how is 

inc(i);
Timer1.Enabled := i < StrToInt(Edit1.Text);

any different than 

  if i > StrToInt(Edit1.Text) then
    Timer1.Enabled := False
  else
    i :=+ 1;

Comment: @Andreas I think @Bob must have a pre-beta version of Delphi which includes the new `:=+` operator.

Comment: @David - what new operator, as far as I know, it's statue of positive 1.

Answer (score 10):

The line

```
i :=+ 1;
```

assigns the value `+1` (also known as `1`) to the variable named `i`. (That is, if `i` is equal to 55, and you do `i :=+ 1`, then `i` will be equal to `1`.)

Perhaps you are seeking

```
i := i + 1;
```

or

```
inc(i);
```

?

Comment: delphi is an extremely forgiving language

Comment: @Bob: Yes, and as Sertac et. al. correctly pointed out, when you compare `i`, the result is undefined since you haven't told the computer what `i` should be yet.

Comment: -1 - how's even possible, that this absolutely pointless answer has so many pluses. the answer is the i variable is unitialized, because first condition of the event is testing this local variable, which has of course no assigned value.

Comment: @daemon_x: Yes, I agree that it was odd that I missed that part. Of course, I could have added it, but then I would have felt like I stole the points that rightfully should belong to Sertac et. al., who actually was first to observe this obvious error. Nevertheless, I am pretty sure that the OP intends to increment `i` in the timer, so I am not entirely sure that my answer is "absolutely pointless". I will consider deleting it, since Sertac et. al. have pointed out the "worst" problem in the OP's code, but still, I think the `inc(i)` issue is worth pointing out, so I don't know...

Comment: @Andreas - (Considering `i` is a global) without the `inc`, the `i >` test would have no point, I agree the intention was to increment it. Since there are multiple errors on the question and since there's no answer that sums up all, IMHO, better let the answer stay.

Comment: @Sertac - but the local variable has the higher priority than the global one when they have the same name. So this means nothing else that the variable i is uninitialized even if he has some global i parameter.

Comment: @daemon - Agreed. What I meant is if the OP decided that the variable should be global instead of local and corrected it, the code still would not execute as expected, unless its value is incremented in the OnTimer event.

Answer (score 5):

You're not initializing `i`, it is a local variable. Hence the timer can be enabled or not depending on the arbitrary value it's memory location holds.

Comment: ive tryed making it a global variable and setting it when the form is created.. doesnt effect it...

Answer (score 0):

This is a well case that people just ignore the Warning message.
I wish that compiler should spit out Hint or Error and No Warning. Warning is just a case that short comming from compiler and it should be fixed at later version.

Cheers